# Adjust query to show if column in table is a primary key column

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this query

```
SQL> select a.table_name,
  2         count_rows(a.table_name) total_rows,
  3         max(a.column_id) total_cols,
  4         pk_cols(a.table_name) primkey_cols
  5  from user_tab_columns a
  6  group by a.table_name;

TABLE_NAME      TOTAL_ROWS TOTAL_COLS PRIMKEY_COLS
--------------- ---------- ---------- -------------------------
DEPT                     4          3 DEPTNO
SO_TEST                  0          1
TEST                     7          3 ORD, TERMREGIONAL
EMP                     14          8 EMPNO
TRAINING                 0          5 TRAINING_PLACE_ID
TEMP_SE                 10          3
<snip>
```

I am trying to make following changes

```
   TABLE_NAME       TOTAL_ROWS COLUMN_NAME DATATYPE    PRIMKEY_COLS
    --------------- ---------- ----------  --------     ------------
    DEPT                     4   DEPTNO.    NUMBER.       YES
                                 DNAME.    VARCHAR.       NO
                                 LOC       VARCHAR.       NO
    EMP.                    14   EMPNO.     NUMBER.       YES
                                 ENAME.    VARCHAR.       NO
                                   JOB.    VARCHAR        NO
                                   MGR.     NUMBER.       NO
                               HIREDATE       DATE.       NO
                                    SAL.    NUMBER.       NO
<SNIP>
```

Below is my current query

```
SQL> select a.table_name,
      2         count_rows(a.table_name) total_rows,
      3         a.column_name,
      4         a.data_type 
      5  from user_tab_columns a
      6  group by a.table_name;
   
    
       TABLE_NAME       TOTAL_ROWS COLUMN_NAME DATATYPE    
        --------------- ---------- ----------  --------    
        DEPT                     4   DEPTNO.    NUMBER.       
        DEPT                     4    DNAME.    VARCHAR.       
        DEPT                     4      LOC       VARCHAR.    
        EMP.                    14   EMPNO.     NUMBER.       
        EMP                     14   ENAME.    VARCHAR.        
        EMP                     14     JOB.    VARCHAR         
        EMP                     14      MGR.     NUMBER.       
        EMP                     14  HIREDATE       DATE.       
        EMP                     14       SAL.    NUMBER.       
    <SNIP>
```

As you see table and total rows are repeating for each column within a table and I also didn't understand how to make yes or no values if the particular column is primary key or not

how to get the desired op?

Notes :the earlier query which has total rows count and consolidated primary key columns is done by using to functions which are called into query

function for total rows :

```
SQL> create or replace function count_rows (par_table_name in varchar2)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    -- return number of rows in PAR_TABLE_NAME
  5    retval number;
  6  begin
  7    execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' ||
  8      dbms_assert.sql_object_name(par_table_name) into retval;
  9    return retval;
 10  end;
 11  /
```

function for aggregate list of primary keys in table (now I dont need this instead I need yes or no next to the respective column)

```
SQL> create or replace function pk_cols (par_table_name in varchar2)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    -- return list of primary key columns for PAR_TABLE_NAME, sorted by column's
  5    -- position within the primary key constraint
  6    retval varchar2(100);
  7  begin
  8    select listagg(b.column_name, ', ') within group (order by b.position)
  9      into retval
 10      from user_constraints a join user_cons_columns b on b.constraint_name = a.constraint_name
 11      where upper(a.table_name) = dbms_assert.sql_object_name(upper(par_table_name))
 12        and a.constraint_type = 'P';
 13    return retval;
 14  end;
 15  /

Function created.
```

Comment: You're pretty close already, just outer join `user_constraints` and `join user_cons_columns` into your query, and use case to print yes / no if the value in user_constraints isn't null / is null.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
SQL> break on table_name on total_rows on total_cols
SQL>
SQL> select a.table_name,
  2         count_rows(a.table_name) total_rows,
  3         a.column_name,
  4         a.data_type,
  5         max(a.column_id) over (partition by a.table_name order by null) total_cols,
  6         --
  7         case when ucc.column_name = a.column_name then 'YES'
  8              else 'NO'
  9         end primkey_col
 10  from user_tab_columns a
 11    left join user_constraints uc on uc.table_name = a.table_name
 12      and uc.constraint_type = 'P'
 13    left join user_cons_columns ucc on ucc.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
 14      and ucc.column_name = a.column_name
 15  order by a.table_name, a.column_id;
```

---

```
TABLE_NAME TOTAL_ROWS COLUMN_NAM DATA_TYPE    TOTAL_COLS PRI
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------ ---------- ---
BONUS               0 ENAME      VARCHAR2              5 NO
                      JOB        VARCHAR2                NO
                      SAL        NUMBER                  NO
                      COMM       NUMBER                  NO
                      EMPNO      NUMBER                  YES
DEPT                4 DEPTNO     NUMBER                3 YES
                      DNAME      VARCHAR2                NO
                      LOC        VARCHAR2                NO
EMP                14 EMPNO      NUMBER                8 YES
                      ENAME      VARCHAR2                NO
                      JOB        VARCHAR2                NO
                      MGR        NUMBER                  NO
                      HIREDATE   DATE                    NO
                      SAL        NUMBER                  NO
                      COMM       NUMBER                  NO
                      DEPTNO     NUMBER                  NO
SALGRADE            5 GRADE      NUMBER                3 NO
                      LOSAL      NUMBER                  NO
                      HISAL      NUMBER                  NO

19 rows selected.

SQL>
```